# Git - Can't do pull request after revert

Tags: git

I've created a pull request to merge the branch `foo` to `master`. I then accepted the PR and merged. After that I had to revert that merge again, because I noticed I accidentially merged before the code was tested by our test team.

But if I make the Pull Request again, then it says the branches are identical.

Is this normal? How am I supposed to make a PR again now?

Comment: I think the linked answer is an exact dupe. Let me know if it isn't